# Way to make a mutable map immutable without copying

Tags: scala, dictionary, immutability, mutable

I want to convert a mutable map into an immutable map inside of a closed scope. Here's a sample code of the situation and nonsense defensive copy:

```
def func(): immutable.Map[String, Int] = {
    val map = mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
    // here goes operations for the map
    return immutable.HashMap ++ map
}
```

As I wrote "nonsense", doing defensive copy here is totally wasting, since the mutable map is actually immutable from outside. If we can make only the getter operations seenable from outside, it should be better for the performance.

The problem is that I really don't know how to do it. I tried simply wrapping it by an anonymous immutable map instance, but the method `def +[B1 >: B](kv: (A, B1))` makes it impossible.

Please help me!

EDIT: just forgot to fix the returned type `[Int, Int]` to `[String, Int]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return simply `collection.Map`, which is a common supertype of `collection.mutable.Map` and `collection.immutable.Map`:

```
def func(): collection.Map[Int, Int] = {
  val map = mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
  // here goes operations for the map
  return map
}
```

The users could cast it to `mutable.Map`, but they could also get the mutable map by reflection in any solution which avoids copying, or mutate the immutable map even when you do copy.

Comment: I want the returned map to be immutable map, but collection.Map looks immutable as well. I'm so confused... Could you tell me what immutable.Map does by inheriting collection.Map if you didn't mind? :/

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Brilliant! Short and to the point. Sometimes the collection library seems so complex and contains too many traits but then you see this and understand.

Comment: @RyoichiroOka They have (basically) the same API. `immutable.Map` is actually immutable (short of using reflection, as mentioned); `collection.Map` can be either mutable or immutable (but even if it's mutable, you can't access the mutating methods without casting it).